# Soap 1.1 Wsdl support issue?

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

i am just trying to add a service refrence through wsdl on client side but its not picking the generted wsdl

then i find a sample wsdl pnline and try to import it and it works fine so kindly can someone tell me what changes i do made in notworking wsdl to to make it logically be like "working one"

Working one:

```
     <definitions name="HelloService"
       targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
       xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
       xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

       <message name="SayHelloRequest">
          <part name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
       </message>

       <message name="SayHelloResponse">
          <part name="greeting" type="xsd:string"/>
       </message>

       <portType name="Hello_PortType">
          <operation name="sayHello">
             <input message="tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
             <output message="tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
          </operation>
       </portType>

       <binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
          <soap:binding style="rpc"
             transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
          <operation name="sayHello">
             <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello"/>
             <input>
                <soap:body
                   encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
                   use="encoded"/>
             </input>

             <output>
                <soap:body
                   encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
                   use="encoded"/>
             </output>
          </operation>
       </binding>
   <service name="Hello_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
      <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
         <soap:address
            location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

and not working one(my generted wsdl) :

```
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="RoutingService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://10.111.21.97:8884/?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://10.111.21.97:8884/?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IRoutingService_RouteEnd_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RouteEnd"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IRoutingService_RouteEnd_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RouteEndResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IRoutingService_RouteRequest_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RouteRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IRoutingService_RouteRequest_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RouteRequestResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IRoutingService_Test_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Test"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IRoutingService_Test_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IRoutingService">
    <wsdl:operation name="RouteEnd">
    <wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/RouteEnd" message="tns:IRoutingService_RouteEnd_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/RouteEndResponse" message="tns:IRoutingService_RouteEnd_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RouteRequest">
    <wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/RouteRequest" message="tns:IRoutingService_RouteRequest_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/RouteRequestResponse" message="tns:IRoutingService_RouteRequest_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Test">
    <wsdl:input wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/Test" message="tns:IRoutingService_Test_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsam:Action="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/TestResponse" message="tns:IRoutingService_Test_OutputMessage"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingService" type="tns:IRoutingService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="RouteEnd">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/RouteEnd" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RouteRequest">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/RouteRequest" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Test">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IRoutingService/Test" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="RoutingService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IRoutingService">
    <soap:address location="http://10.111.21.97:8884/Soap"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

And i am hosting the soap service through code

```
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        var serviceMetaDataBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled=true, MetadataExporter = { PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15 }};

        _webserviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetaDataBehaviour);
        _webserviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRoutingService), binding, "Soap");
        //_webserviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
        _webserviceHost.Open();
```

Kindly assist
And i have to generate Soap1.1 compatible wsdl i induce from all this